# Auto refresh a page after editing & saving in lightning datatable is not working?. Can anyone help me with that issue?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Component:

hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                                 onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"
                                 onsave="{!c.saveRecord}"
                                 draftvalues="{!v.draftValues}"/>

CONTROLLER:

```
    handleRowAction : function (component, event, helper) {
        var action = event.getParam('action');
        console.log(action);
        var row = event.getParam('row');
        alert('Edit Details: '+row);
        if ( action.name == 'Edit' ) {
            alert('Edit Function');
            //debugger;
            var selectedMenuItemValue = event.getParam("row").Id;
            console.log('selectedvalue-->'+selectedMenuItemValue);
            var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
            editRecordEvent.setParams({
                "recordId": selectedMenuItemValue
            });
            editRecordEvent.fire();
        }
       else if(action.name == 'Delete'){

           alert('delete');
           var msg ='Are you sure you want to delete this Case?';
           if(!confirm(msg)){
               return false;

           }
           else
           {    
               var row = event.getParam('row');
               console.log(row);
               var recId= event.getParam("row").Id;
               console.log("in delete");
               console.log(recId);
               var action=component.get("c.deleteRecord");
               action.setParams({"recId":recId});
               action.setCallback(this, function(b)
                                  {  
                                      var state = b.getState();
                                      console.log(state);
                                      if (state === "SUCCESS")
                                      {
                                          var resultToast=$A.get("e.force:showToast");
                                          resultToast.setParams({ "title": "Success",
                                                                 "message": "The record was deleted.",type:'success'});
                                          resultToast.fire();
                                          // $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                                          location.reload();
                                      }                                       
                                  })
           }
                $A.enqueueAction(action);           
       }
   } 
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. This is _way_ too much code and not enough detail. Please [edit] your post to give a detailed description, in the body, of the behavior and the issue that you are struggling with, then cut the code down to just what we need to see to troubleshoot the issue. See [ask] for more.

Comment: Please also note that you should use the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code or it will be unreadable. I've done that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Helper method, you have `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` taking place after the `$A.enqueue()` method, which effectively means that it executes before the action itself runs.

If you're going to use `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();`, always put it within the successful `action` execution code.

**Also worth noting** - that `e.force:refreshView` only updates standard lightning components on the current lightning page you're looking at.  In order to refresh/reload the data in one of your custom lightning components, you'll need to reload that data manually in your component code.